# How to insert in javascript file php variables?

Tags: php, javascript, variables, include

My page is available in 3 languages and I'm including in the header of each file (index, contact, etc.) the selected language file (en, ru, pl).

```
<?php
session_start();
include('language/'.$_SESSION['lang'].'.php');
?>
```

**en.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$lang = array();

$lang['hello'] = 'Hello';
$lang['world'] = 'World !';
?>
```

**ru.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$lang = array();

$lang['hello'] = 'привет';
$lang['world'] = 'мир';
?>
```

And this is how I'm echoing them:

```
<p><? echo $lang['hello'].' '.$lang['world'];?></p>
```

This is working actually fine, but I'm having problem with my .js files. If I want to alert or insert some text somewhere I can't.

For example in one of my .js file I have an alert:

```
if (something_obj.val() == ''){
   alert('Wrong username given !');
   return false;
}
```

How can I implement language files in my js files? Am I need to create a news .js language file?

Comment: You can use JSON. 
See the following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5619038/290172

Comment: The answer for JavaScript has already been given. However, for translations in PHP; Why re-invent the wheel? Most PHP installations have [gettext](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettext.php) installed. Gettext is a standardised way to translate strings in your application and uses separate 'translation' files (.po/.mo) that contain translations per language. You can translate a string by setting the current 'locale' and translating the text via `_('text-to-translate')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have one js file per language with translations looking like this:

```
// german.js
var translations = {
  'hello': 'hallo',
  'world': 'welt'
};
```

In other JS scripts, just do something like this:

```
alert(translations['hello'] + " " + translations['world'])
```

Of course, you might want to choose a shorter variable name than `translations`.

Then, in your php file, include the correct JS script based on the language:

```
<script src="languages/<?php echo $_SESSION['lang']; ?>.js"></script>
```

Comment: +1 For translations in JavaScript, it is common practice to use separate .js files per language for an example, have a look at the jquery-ui date picker; [jquery-ui.datepicker-fr.js](http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/jquery.ui.datepicker-fr.js).

Answer (score 1):

You can create new file - for example `js.php` which will load proper language file and print out all variables into JavaScript array:

`js.php`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var lang = {
<?php
session_start();
include('language/'.$_SESSION['lang'].'.php');

$data = array();
foreach ( $lang as $key => $value ) {
  $data[] = '"' . $key . '" : "' . $value . '"';
}
echo implode(',', $data);
?>
};
</script>
```

Then include this file on the page which have to use JavaScript translation array and use it with:

```
alert(lang.key);
```

Also if there will be `"` sign in the translation string, you have to escape it with `\"`, for example with:

```
$value = str_replace('"', '\"', $value);
```

Comment: Not a good idea unless you don't mind that caching won't work, I think.

Comment: It's just an idea which can be extended with cache feature, etc.