# PHP string array to javascript string array parsing error

Tags: php, javascript, arrays

I've tried

```
var name = <?php echo json_encode($eventname); ?>;
```

and

```
var name = new Array("<?php echo implode('","', $eventName);?>");
```

to parse my name string array from PHP to Javascript. It displayed as

```
var name = ["lalalala","Lalala","test"];
```

and

```
var name = new Array("lalalala","Lalala","test");
```

in viewsource, but when I tried to use name[i] to get the string, it returned the character, not the string. The size of the array name is also not 3, but 20 (which is the total number of characters plus three ","). How can I fix this?

Comment: can you show how you are using `name[i]` to get the data?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert php array to Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618925/convert-php-array-to-javascript)

Comment: I used console.log(name[i]) to display this in console

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty sure because 'name' points to window.name (Thanks [Fabrício Matté](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1331430/fabricio-matte)). [Look Here](http://www.quackit.com/javascript/javascript_reserved_words.cfm)

It works fine if you change 'name' to 'names'.

Comment: It is not "reserved", but rather it points to `window.name`, an already existing property of the global object (`window`).

Comment: My bad :) so you're saying this.name might work under a class?

Comment: Exactly. `=]` Anywhere that is not in the global scope. Try on console `(function(){ var name=1; alert(name); }());`.

Comment: Thank you so much! After changing it to names it works now! :)