# how to assign value in location array for google map?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have an array {`$address = array(..........);`}
I have converted it like 
{

```
foreach ($address as $key => $val){
    $points[] = "['{$val}', '{$val}']";
}
$output = join ("," , $points);
$req_format = strip_tags($output);
```

}

which outputs: 
['30 South Wacker Drive Floor 22 Chicago IL 60606 ', '30 South Wacker Drive Floor 22 Chicago IL 60606 '],['288 Bishopsgate London, EC2M 4QP United Kingdom ', '288 Bishopsgate London, EC2M 4QP United Kingdom '],['260 Madison Avenue 8th Floor New York NY 10016 ', '260 Madison Avenue 8th Floor New York NY 10016 ']

I need to assign this value to a js variable:

```
var locationsArray = [
['30 South Wacker Drive Floor 22 Chicago IL 60606', '30 South Wacker Drive Floor 22 Chicago IL 60606'],
['30 South Wacker Drive Floor 22 Chicago IL 60606', '30 South Wacker Drive Floor 22 Chicago IL 60606']
];
```

how can I assign php variable $req_format equal to js variable locationArray = [??????];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($address as $key => $val){
    $val = strip_tags($val);
    $points[] = array($val, $val);
}
$json = json_encode($points);
$json = str_replace('\n',' ',$json);
$json = str_replace('\r',' ',$json);

var locations = '<?php echo $json;?>';
var locations_array = JSON.parse(locations);

var locationsArray = locations_array;
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use json instead, like

```
foreach ($address as $key => $val){
    $points[] = "['{$val}', '{$val}']";
}
$jsoned = json_encode($points);
//pass it to your js
var js_data = "<?php echo $jsoned; ?>";
```

Comment: it doesn't work.. `var locationsArray = ["<?php echo $jsoned; ?>";];`

Comment: you provide the alternate method to encode, but need to assign encoded code to js variable....at the end, i need the variable in this format `var locationsArray = [
['30 South Wacker Drive Floor 22 Chicago IL 60606', '30 South Wacker Drive Floor 22 Chicago IL 60606'],
['30 South Wacker Drive Floor 22 Chicago IL 60606', '30 South Wacker Drive Floor 22 Chicago IL 60606']
];`

Comment: @user2471896 see this:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618925/convert-php-array-to-javascript , this should help

Comment: Sorry I am not getting the variable in required format....that just shows assigning the values to js array.

Comment: please see my answer for the exact outpu...I have found the way now :)