# How to convert php array to js array?

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps

I have a php array which i need to convert and assign that to `var locationsArray`

required format:

```
var locationsArray = [
    ['Google Official','1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, USA'],
    ['Google 1','112 S. Main St., Ann Arbor, USA'], 
    ['Google 2','10 10th Street NE, Suite 600 USA']
];
```

Comment: Can you show your php array please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    foreach ($address as $key => $val){
                                    $val = strip_tags($val);
                                    $points[] = array($val, $val);
                                }
                                $json = json_encode($points);
                                $json = str_replace('\n',' ',$json);
                                $json = str_replace('\r',' ',$json);

var locations = '<?php echo $json;?>';
var locations_array = JSON.parse(locations);

var locationsArray = locations_array;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
$NewJsonData = json_encode(locationsArray);
echo $NewJsonData;  //Alert it in javascript
```

Try this [**LINK**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

**You can assign the variable $NewJsonData to your js variable**

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17036886/how-to-assign-value-in-location-array-for-google-map]

Comment: what is the link...??you got the ans there or what

Comment: this js variable is fixed....need to assign php array equal to this variable in same format like it is.

Comment: link is for more description, havn't got the answer yet

Comment: yes the result value $NewJsonData ,you can assign it to js variable

Comment: See my comment I also suggested the same

Comment: actually i am adding locations to google map, so it requires the exact format addressess. `var locationsArray = [
    ['Google Official','1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, USA'],
    ['Google 1','112 S. Main St., Ann Arbor, USA'], 
    ['Google 2','10 10th Street NE, Suite 600 USA']
];`

Comment: and these addressess are written static, but i need to assign dynamically with php array list.

Answer (score 0):

This will be something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var locationsArray = <?php echo json_encode(array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5)); ?>
</script>
```

Don't know php syntax, sorry :) [ref](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: `Array
(
    [0] => 30 South Wacker Drive

Floor 22

Chicago

IL 60606


    [1] => 288 Bishopsgate

London, EC2M 4QP

United Kingdom


    [2] => 260 Madison Avenue

8th Floor

New York

NY 10016




    [3] => 315 Montgomery Street

8th Floor

San Francisco

CA 94104`

Comment: need to make like "locationsArray" and assign equal to js var in given format.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
<?php
$php_array = array('abc','def','ghi');
$js_array = json_encode($php_array);
echo "var javascript_array = ". $js_array . ";\n";
?>
</script>
```

Comment: it is assigning the value to javascript_array, but not in the format I required(format shown in the question)