# Assigning values to characters in php and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

```
$cw = array(chr(0)=>455,chr(1)=>455,...,'E'=>521,...chr(134)=>353,chr(135)=>353,...chr(255)=>465);
```

I have this file that defines an array as seen above (I have just shown a bit of the array for conciseness). Is this array assigning integer values to all of the ascii characters? If so why and also, how do I convert it to JavaScript?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: 1) Yeah, it does appear to be a mapping of characters to integers. 2) What would you suppose is the equivalent in JavaScript? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I don't find it appropriate to explain to you why your code is defining any variables of an array, but please see this post on how to convert a php array to javascript.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5619038/367456

Or you may use
`var js_array = [<?php echo '"'.implode('","', $php_array).'"' ?>];`