# passing array as javascript function argument from php

Tags: javascript, php

I need to pass an array as a function argument from php to js.I need a way to pass them to the function.Can anyone please help me with this. Thanks a lot..

Comment: Please show the code you've tried so far :)

Comment: refer below link, this make it easy

*http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618925/convert-php-array-to-javascript*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your PHP array to JS Object (in JSON).

```
var obj = <?= json_encode($phpArr); ?>;

myAwesomeFunction(obj);
```

Comment: you should avoid using `<?=` instead use `<?php echo `

Comment: Whay you think so? It's easy for me. And my servers are always have `short_open_tag=1`.

Comment: short_open_tag does not relate to short echo tag since PHP 5.4

Comment: `echo also has a shortcut syntax, where you can immediately follow the opening tag with an equals sign. Prior to PHP 5.4.0, this short syntax only works with the short_open_tag configuration setting enabled.` This means, 5.4.0 and more, you can write `<?=` even your short_open_tag is 0. So it's not poor practice. It's even better one.

Comment: @plutov: Wuss :)  You were right.  Why change it?

Comment: @cHao, for other ineterests:)

Comment: thanks all for helping me