# Copying array values from php to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have a php array

```
array(6) { 
   ["merchant_id"]=> string(6) "ajeesh" 
   ["passkey"]=> string(4) "1234" 
   ["amt"]=> string(5) "10.00" 
   ["email"]=> string(16) "ajeesh@gmail.com" 
   ["mobileNo"]=> string(10) "9874563210" 
   ["orderID"]=> string(6) "123456" 
}
```

which I got as a result of `var_dump($_POST)`.

How can I copy all this value to a javascript array variable?How can it be possible? Suppose if the javascript array I made is

```
var thisSession = new Array();
```

**TRY**

I have tried this in the javascript

```
<script>
window.onload = function getApp(){
    var thisSession = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($_POST); ?>');
    alert (thisSession);
}
</script>
```

and this in the php

```
json_encode($_POST);
```

but the javascript is alerting "Object object".Im not gettign the array!why?

Comment: use `json_encode()` function http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: Can you be more specefic.Ill check the documentation.

Comment: json_encode() returns the JSON representation of your array

You have to use the return in javascript in a second time

Comment: maybe this link can help?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618925/convert-php-array-to-javascript

Comment: So as you gathered `json_encode` + _don't use `new Array();` in JS_ Use the literal notation `var anArray = [];` It's shorter and can't result in unexpected behaviour in the same way the constructor can

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JSON, encode the PHP variable, then parse it in JS:

```
var thisSession = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($_POST); ?>');
```

Comment: Oh thanks. let me try that and will let know about it

Comment: No problem, I wrote this from the top of my head, so it might need tweaking, but the concept has to work. For example: `JSON.parse('{"foo":"bar","baz":"long"}')`

Comment: yeah sure,Ill let you know

Comment: It's because JS doesn't have associative arrays like PHP does. It uses objects instead. Try replacing alert with console.log and see the whole object in the console: `console.log(thisSession);`

Comment: One more thing I wish asking you,fromthe parsed array in the javascript,is it possible for search for somthing in it?or if I want to get each element in that array seperately what can I do?I will not get it by var a=thisSession[0]; to get the first element I guess?

Comment: No, you need to specify the keys, like: `thisSession.merchant_id` or `thisSession['merchant_id']`... Or, loop through all the properties like: `for (var i in thisSession) {alert('key: ' + i + ' value: ' + thisSession[i])};`

Answer (score 1):

using php's `json_encode` & javascript's `JSON.parse`

```
var thisSession=JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($phparray)?>');
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**
If you want to access `merchant_id` you simply do

```
alert(thisSession.merchand_id);
```

**Here, you need to `json_encode` the php data to use in javascript**

```
  $array = json_encode($_POST);
```

**In your html**

```
<script>
var data = JSON.parse("<?php echo $array; ?>"); // your new javascript object
</script>
```

Reference  http://www.php.net/json_encode

Comment: add quotes before and after the php echo.& JSON.parse.else it won't work.

Comment: @cocco that would actually return just a string and would require additinal parsing

Comment: Thanks I wish I could upvote.Once Im capable I will.Your answer helped!

Comment: Welcome, glad that it's helpful

Answer (score -2):

There is no comparable object (associative array) in *JavaScript* to that which you've shown us in your example. You'd either have to use two *Arrays* or lose the ordering (and ability to have multiple keys of the same name) by using an *Object*. This second option is what [`json_encode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) will result in.

Comment: ordering doesnt matter.But I just want to have all those values which is in the php to a javascript array