# php in javascript is it possible

Tags: javascript

The headline is properly pretty bad, but i don't know what to name it.. Anyways:
I have this simple problem with a javascript code that i want to display some php code, but i don't know how to do it.. Here is the code:

```
   var bigData = {
"teams" : [],
"results" : [] };

for( var i=1 ; i<16 ; i+=2 )
   { 
    bigData.teams.push(["<?php echo 1; ?>",'Team '+(i+1)]);
}

for( var j=1 ; j<16 ; j++ ) {
  bigData.results.push([1,2]);
}
```

As you see im trying to just print something in php inside the javascript but i can't. Any one who got a solution?

Best regards Emil

Comment: Where this code is located?

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean by located?

Comment: you've shown us the code. Did you get it out of your head or from some file?

Comment: it's a script that's create a tournament tree. I just need to write the team with php..

Comment: okay, and where that script is stored? A separate `.js` file?

Comment: As long as your code is in a PHP file (i.e. *.php), and not a javascript file (i.e. *.js), you can do this without any problem. Your server-side values will be available when the page is rendered.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert php array to Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618925/convert-php-array-to-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

add this tag on your html file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript.php"></script>
```

in your javascript.php file:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type:text/javascript");
$arr = array();
echo 'var array_data = [';
for( $i = 0; $i < 10; $i++ ){
  $arr[] = "[{$i},'Team {$i}']";
};
echo implode(",",$arr);
echo ']';
```

then in your js file you will have a js array called `array_data` then you can iterate over it

Comment: will be much better a json service called over rest verbs with some cache, but it will need a more complex explanation, just to give some guidelines the solution fits