# Transform a PHP array to a Javascript array

Tags: javascript, php

Basically I used these codes to transform:

```php
echo "<script>";
echo " var img_array=new Array();";
foreach($img_arr as $img_url){
      $url=(string)$img_url;
      echo "img_array.push('".$url."');";
}

echo "console.log(img_array);";
echo "</script>";
```

However, errors occur(firefox debug window) :

```
Error: unterminated string literal
Source File: http://127.0.0.1/CubeCart/index.php?_a=account
Line: 1, Column: 42
Source Code:
    var img_array=new Array();img_array.push('http://gtms01.alicdn.com/tps/i1/T1mL3LFhhhXXaCwpjX.png
```

but after I checked the souce file of the html page, the script is shown like this:

```
<script> var img_array=new Array();img_array.push('http://gtms01.alicdn.com/tps/i1/T1mL3LFhhhXXaCwpjX.png
      ');img_array.push('http://gtms01.alicdn.com/tps/i1/T1DQtTFsdFXXaCwpjX.png');console.log(img_array);</script>
```

With which I don't see anything is wrong.

Comment: See if this helps http://us3.php.net/json_encode

Comment: Maby this could help! 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618925/convert-php-array-to-javascript

Comment: [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5619163/2598994) check if this could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a newline in one of the items in your your php array. Use this:

```
echo "<script>";
echo " var img_array=new Array();";
foreach($img_arr as $img_url){
    $url=(string)$img_url;
    echo "img_array.push('". htmlentities(trim($url))."');";
}

echo "console.log(img_array);";
echo "</script>";
```

Comment: And what if it contains or newline in the middle? Or single quote? Or `'); alert("SURPRISE");//` ?

Comment: Not the best way to get the desired result, but this _should_  fix the OP's question, at least in the case that threw that specific error. I don't think this deserves a downvote.

Comment: `htmlentities` escapes HTML control characters, not JavaScript ones. In particular, it doesn't fix any of mentioned by my comment issues.

Comment: Very well what do you propose?

Comment: The only correct solution would be `json_encode`, although `addcslashes` might do the job.

Answer (score 6):

```
$jsArray = json_encode ($phpArray);
```

Comment: in addition to this - recommended - answer, don't forget to use `JSON.parse(json_string)` in js to get an array back.

Comment: @KarelG: You don't need to, valid JSON is valid JavaScript.

Comment: @elclanrs : uhm, i have said _in js_, because `json_encode` results into a string. By using `JSON.parse()`, you get an array for js, something the OP is asking for.

Comment: OP is _printing_ JSON not _parsing_. This works just fine `var array = <?= json_encode(array(1,2,3)) ?>`