# Passing PHP string array to JavaScript array as JSON not working?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I’m trying to transform an array from PHP to JavaScript but it doesn’t seem to work. Here’s my PHP code `query.php`:

```
$query = 'SELECT coupon FROM '.$disc;
$coupdb = array();
$results = $newdb->get_results($query);
foreach( $results as $result )
$coupdb[] = $result->coupon;

echo $coupdb[0]; //This shows perfectly the content but I want to send this array to a Javascript file.
```

I've tried too with JSON:

```
$coupdb_js = json_encode($coupdb);
```

Here's my JavaScript file `discount.js`:

```
var coupdb = <?php echo $coupdb ?>;
alert(coupdb[0]);
```

And with JSON:

```
var coupdb = <?php echo $coupdb_js ?>;
alert(coupdb[0]);
```

Comment: `var coupdb = <?= json_encode($coupdb_js) ?>;`. Did you look at the generated JS? It should be obvious that `var coupdb = Array;` is not correct.

Comment: yeah, you're not actually json encoding anything. It just tries to turn it into a string, which doesn't work. And you don't try to json decode it either

Comment: Sorry, I was editing the question. @Markasoftware $newdb It's my Wordpress external database connection. The query is working, I can show the array with: echo $coupdb[0]; or echo $coupdb[1];

Comment: What is the result of the `alert( coupdb );`? Do you get an alert dialog? What does it say?

Also, are you testing this with a web server? Are you sure it runs your `.js`-file as a PHP script?

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618925/convert-php-array-to-javascript/5619038#5619038).

Comment: @Jon shows me an "Unexpected token <"... It takes the <? as unknown token.

Comment: @JakeGould I'm calling the .js via form and a button on it. Everything It's working but I can't pass the PHP array to Javascript.

Comment: @lschessinger yeah, tried it before post but didn't work.

Comment: @fredrikhl you're right, I think my server It's not running my .js as a PHP script, because It's not able to recognize <?php ?>

Comment: Why is there no `JSON.parse()` anywhere? It's not going to work without that

Answer (score 0):

> @Jon shows me an "Unexpected token `<`"... It takes the `<?` as unknown token.

So your PHP isn't being processed. If this is in a `.js` file, it won't work unless the server is set up to process those files (bad idea)

Instead, this should probably be in a `<script>` tag in your HTML, or perhaps better as an AJAX call.

Comment: You're totally right, this is in a .js file and can't recognize php tags.

Comment: I'm sorry @JakeGould it's hard to figure out because there's a lot of code to paste. But the resume is that I've been proving to pass $coupdb[] to a .js file with and without json with bad results. Seems like there's a problem with the php tags interpretation.. and if I use the <script> tags, then there's a problem with <script> tags. Gonna read something more about Wordpress javascript standards.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've found a way, It's an easy way but maybe not the best one :)

From my php I've sent the coupdb variable catched from bbdd to javascript file:

```
<?php
$DB_USER="dbuser";
$DB_PASSWORD="passdb";
$DB_NAME="dbname";
$DB_HOST="dbhost";

$newdb = new wpdb($DB_USER, $DB_PASSWORD, $DB_NAME, $DB_HOST);
$disc="discounts";


$query = 'SELECT coupon FROM '.$disc;
        $coupdb = array();
        $results = $newdb->get_results($query);
        foreach( $results as $result )
        $coupdb[] = $result->coupon;

?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var coupdb = <?php echo json_encode($coupdb); ?>;
</script>
```

And in js file I used the variable normally:

```
alert (coupdb[0]);
```