# echo PHP array in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, echo

Answer from here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/12863675/894470 is how to assign array to variable.

I'm getting my data from php but when I echo it inside javscript like  example below my chart wont draw.

```
var month_data= [<?php echo json_encode($lol); ?>];
```

but I can show alert and see all my data no problem like below:

[image]

If I copy the text from alert and paste it in array like below:

```
var month_data= [{month: '2014-01', KFC: 0, PizzaHut: 1},{month: '2014-03', KFC: 2, PizzaHut: 1},{month: '2014-04', KFC: 1, PizzaHut: 0},{month: '2014-05', KFC: 0, PizzaHut: 1},{month: '2014-07', KFC: 1, PizzaHut: 0},{month: '2014-10', KFC: 42, PizzaHut: 42}];
```

my chart will draw. What is wrong here??

**UPDATE**: My query:

```
$lol = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    $lol[] =   "{month: '". $row['year'] ."-". $row['month'] ."', KFC: ". $row['kfc'] .", PizzaHut: ". $row['pizzahut'] ."}";
}
```

and I'm using `Morris.js`: http://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/ to generate my chart.

Comment: Regarding your update: **Never** build json-strings by hand. Allways build a valid php data structure and use json_encode only once.

Comment: Good thing you asked about my array. I thought the problem was with how I echo array in javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a real PHP structure to encode it into JSON, not just a string:

```
$lol = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $lol[] = Array(
        "month"    => $row['year'].'-'.$row['month'],
        "KFC"      => $row['kfc'],
        "PizzaHut" => $row['pizzahut']
    );
}
```

and:

```
var month_data = <?php echo json_encode($lol); ?>;
```

`json_encode` will automatically translate `$lol` into a json array containing objects (associative arrays are translated into objects).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It does worked. May I know how I can see my array data? `alert (month_data);` don't show anything.

Comment: OK so googling brought me back to SO about how to see my array data. Really weird because the array data is not in the chart required format but my chart get drawn anyway. I should study this later. Thanks again.

Comment: @sg552 `alert` only shows the result of `month_data.toString()`. To view the entire object, you should use `console.log(month_data)` and look at the result in the debug console of your browser.

Answer (score 1):

All is fine, you just have to parse it to json format, you can do that using:

```
var month_data= JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($lol); ?>');
```

edit your php code like this:

```
$lol[] =   array("month" => $row['year'], "KFC" => $row['kfc'] ...
```

anyway i do not recommend using php in js, the better way would be to put the content from the variable somewhere in html and than to take it with js.

Comment: If injected directly into js-code, there is no need to parse it as this will be done by the browser/js-interpreter.

Comment: Unfortunately this `var month_data= JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($lol); ?>');` does not work.

Comment: Well, i just tried my code without JSON.parse and the browser didn`t see it as an object

Comment: I believe that the problem is it in your $lol variable, can you show me the error which is appearing or the content of the variable.

Comment: Hi, I appreciate you're trying to help me. Fortunately it has been solved. My mistakes is with how I build my array. Thanks again.