# How can i change php array to javascript array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I get array from php,and then use to change js array and display but its show all elements as an array.##

`$name = array('A','B','C','D');`

```
<script> 
     <?php echo "var name='".json_encode($name)."';";   ?>
     for (var i in name){
                        alert(name[i]);
                         }
</script>
```

Comment: Many duplicates on SO, many results in Google :-|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
<?php
$name = array('A','B','C','D');
$js_array = json_encode($name );
echo "var javascript_array = ". $js_array . ";\n";
?>
</script>
```

[Reffer this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5619038/4595675)

**Note** 
`json_encode()` is only available in PHP 5.2 and up

Answer (score 1):

No need to wrap the value in `''`, if you wrap it the value will be considered as a string not an array in javascript

```
<?php echo "var name=".json_encode($name).";";   ?>
```