# how to convert array from php into js

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have this array value: `print_r ($array);` which contains 2 data (this is latt and long of my gmap project).

The array is from:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['q'])) {
    $q = $_GET['q'];
    }
$q = isset($_GET['q']) ? $_GET['q'] : '';
$array = array();
$nsUser="SELECT * FROM cliententry WHERE kampusterdekat=:q";
$uQuery = $mydb->prepare ($nsUser);
$uQuery->execute(array(':q' => $q));
while ($result = $uQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { 
    $id=$result['id'];
    $googlemap=$result['googlemap'];
    //echo $googlemap;
    $array[] = $googlemap;
    print_r ($array);
    }
?>
```

When I echo, the result will be like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => -5.364000343425874, 105.24465411901474
)
Array
(
    [0] => -5.364000343425874, 105.24465411901474
    [1] => -5.362878747789552, 105.24150252342224
)
```

**Point:**
What I need is to make the result into this format:

    `var wwwsitus = [
      ['<h4>area</h4>', wwwsitus[0]],
      ['<h4>area</h4>', wwwsitus[1]],
    ];`

where locations (`<h4>area</h4>`) are removed. So, it must be, as follows:
    `var wwwsitus = [
      [...,...],
      [...,....],
    ];`

**Note**:
Since I've no capable about array in JS, please help me to fix my title based on my issue. Thks in adv.

Comment: What's the issue here exactly? `x` and `y` aren't set that's why there's no marker? The response is returning `-5.364000343425874, 105.24465411901474-5.362878747789552, 105.24150252342224` which looks like it has an issue on formatting the 2 data and when passed the marker, leads to the error.

Comment: @adjuremods: I finally found what the issue is. I just updated my question. It's about separate elements (grabbed from database) into array, and I simple don't know how. - Yes, you're right. pls help me with this

Comment: try to change how the response object looks like. For example, return 2 separate JSON Objects for every row from the database. With that, you'll have to change your implementation to cater to it being created into a Marker.

Comment: @adjuremods, you mean I make 2 ajax(s) to handle the latt and long?. In this project, I will make 5 location shown in the map and that means I have to create 5 ajax-calling for the latt and long?

Comment: In the example I gave in the comment, `wwwsitus` will now be a JSONArray, you'll loop through the array to make the Markers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert php array to Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618925/convert-php-array-to-javascript)

Comment: I close this question since I find the answer at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618925/convert-php-array-to-javascript, thanks for discussion