# converting with json_encode()

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

```
<?php
$array = array("first elem", "second elem");
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var js_array = '<?php echo json_encode($array); ?>';

        for (var i = 0; i < js_array.length; i++)
        {
            document.write(js_array[i]);
            document.write("<br>");
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

I have PHP array with two elements, when I converting this array to javascript array with `json_encode()`javascript divide my PHP array into set of chars, so in javascript array in a result i have a lot of elements. How to convert PHP array with two elements to javascript array with the same two elements?

Comment: Remove single quote from this line `var js_array = '<?php echo json_encode($array); ?>';`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert php array to Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618925/convert-php-array-to-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You php function [json_encode](http://php.net/json_encode) will give you a valid object, that's in fact what it means, **J**ava**S**cript **O**bject **N**otation.

So by using it as it is you will create an object in your JavaScript code. By enclosing it between apostrophes you are making it a string (who's value can be parsed as JSON).

So the simplest change would be to remove the apostrophes. So this line:

```
var js_array = '<?php echo json_encode($array); ?>';
```

Should become

```
var js_array = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>;
```

Comment: @AnthonyGorshenin you are welcome, I am glad it helps

Answer (score 1):

**Replace you code with the following code..**

```
<?php
    $array = array("first elem", "second elem");
    ?>
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            var js_array = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>;

            for (var i = 0; i < js_array.length; i++)
            {
                document.write(js_array[i]);
                document.write("<br>");
            }
        </script>
    </body>
```

**I hope its help you.....**

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have enclosed the json_encode in colons so you are converting it to a string. The javascript it produces is like this:

```
var js_array = '["first elem","second elem"]';
```

Here `js_array` is an string but you want an array. What you have to do is to produce the json directly as it will yield an array:

```
var js_array = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>;
```