# ForEach Array Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, foreach

I have an array in PHP and I would like to loop through it.

Unfortunately, the array gives back this in JavaScript:

```
Array
(
    [data] => 12,11,2,5,6,7,8,9,10,13,14,15,16,17,18
    [0] => 12,11,2,5,6,7,8,9,10,13,14,15,16,17,18
)
```

And not:

```
var myvar = [10, 11, 12, ...];
```

So I cannot loop through it. Any suggestions?

```
<?php
    include("connection.php");

    $query = $handler->query('  SELECT data FROM lista where id=1;');
    $query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_BOTH/*, 'CreaPrezzi'*/);
    $r = $query->fetch();

    print_r($r);

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"getSortable.php"
    }).done(function (list) {

        var sortedList = list;
        sortedList.forEach(function(id) {
           $("#" + id).appendTo("#sortable")
        })

    })
```

Comment: use `json_encode()` when printing the array,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert php array to Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618925/convert-php-array-to-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That kind of output is indeed what you get with `print_r`. Instead use `json_encode` as follows:

```
echo json_encode($r[0]);
```

Then in JavaScript indicate that your are expecting JSON:

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"getSortable.php",
    dataType: "json"    // <!-- add this
}).done( // ...etc
```

As `$r[0]` (in PHP) is a plain string, you'll need to split it into an array, either in PHP, or in JavaScript. In PHP that could be done with `explode`:

```
echo json_encode(explode(",", $r[0]));
```

Or with JavaScript (but then use the first PHP version) you can use `split`:

```
var sortedList = list.split(',');
```

Comment: Looks like it's a good solution but i m still getting the error.

forEach is not a function...

the values now are between double quetes

Comment: did you try the version with explode?

Comment: Yes, this is what i get:
sortedList = "["12","11","2","5","6","7","8","9","10","13","14","15","16","17","18"]"

Comment: In your ajax options, add `dataType: 'json'`

Answer (score -1):

```
    <?php
    include("connection.php");


    $query = $handler->query('  SELECT data FROM lista where id=1;');
    $query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_BOTH/*, 'CreaPrezzi'*/);
    $r = $query->fetch();

   echo json_encode($r);



            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"getSortable.php"
            }).done(function (list) {

                var sortedList = list;

                sortedList.forEach(function(id) {
                    $("#" + id).appendTo("#sortable")
                })

            })
```

Comment: Please add an explanation of the changes you made and why they answer the original question. Don't post "spot the difference" style answers like this.