# Get Javascript variable as an index with PHP array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

Want javascript variable as index variable in php array in javascript.

Code is not working .....

```
<script>
     var total = <?php echo count($resvalue); ?> ; //$resvalue is an array holding the values are 1,2,3,4. total will hold count of that array.
     for(var j=0;j<total;j++)
     {
          <php echo $resvalue[j]; ?> // where j is javascript variable and $resvalue is PHP array
     }
 </script>
```

Comment: JavaScript is executed on the client side, PHP on the server side. You can't mix and match.

Comment: then what will be the solution for this ?

Comment: You can solve your problem by either sending the `$resvalue` to the client using API call, or by using full php code

Comment: Don't know your use case. For the simple code you're showing, you can easily just do everything in PHP.

Comment: can you clarify your question. also, you have an error in your code... `<php echo...` should be `<?php echo...` you also have another error in your for loop. it should be `total.length` and not `total`...

Comment: may this thread can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618925/convert-php-array-to-javascript

Comment: I am new to PHP . the question is can i use Javascript variable in php array as index variable in javascript for loop ?

Comment: No you can't. PHP is exectuted on the server before the page is loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot read values in a php array from javascript. Instead echo the array and turn it into a javascript array and let javascript do the count.

```
<script>
     var resvalue = [<?php echo $resvalue; ?>]; // or something like this
     for(var j=0; j < resvalue.length; j++)
     {
          // your value is available in the js-array
          // resvalue[j]
     }
</script>
```