# How to convert php array to javascript array in php

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I'm working on core php,i need how to convert PHP array to Javascript array please help me,below the my example code this there please check it.

I tried from long time to debug but not getting any leads. please help me in resolving this issue

Here my php array data:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 001-1234567
    [1] => 1234567
    [2] => 12345678
    [3] => 12345678
    [4] => 12345678
)
```

Here javascript array:

```
var cities = [
    "Aberdeen",
    "Ada",
    "Adamsville",
    "Addyston",
    "Adelphi"
];
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert php array to Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618925/convert-php-array-to-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply convert by JSON encode.

```
echo json_encode($your_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script to convert php array to javascript:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
<?php
$php_array = array('abc','def','ghi');
$js_array = json_encode($php_array);
echo "var javascript_array = ". $js_array . ";\n";
?>
</script>
```

Comment: Hi i have this : $locations=array();
    $query =  $conn->query('SELECT `pg_address` FROM `tbl_master_property`');
     while ($row =$query->fetch_assoc()) {
       $locations[] = $row;
    }                                                                                                                                   i have to change to javascript array how please

Comment: Can you use $query->fetch_array() instead of $query->fetch_assoc() ?