# How to echo a JS variable to php?

Tags: javascript, php

Is that possible to pass a JS variable to PHP ?

My code is :

```
document.getElementById('designation_' + i).value = '<?php echo $list[HERE]; ?>';
```

where I is in a `for` loop.

I want to echo the `$list array` in PHP with the index I of my JS (instead of HERE).
First, is that possible? If yes, how?

Comment: `var source = <?php echo json_encode($list); ?>;` then you can just refer to `source[i]`

Comment: PHP is server side. It can output to a DOM, but once the DOM is rendered JavaScript takes over. You can't echo PHP from JS, but you can instantiate JS variables with PHP and console.log that.

Comment: You can try `$i=1` and then `document.getElementById('designation_' + <?php echo $i;?>).value = '<?php echo $list[$i]; ?>';`

Comment: I think that you mean: **from** PHP?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Thanks it works great !!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can not pass the JavaScript variable up to PHP to index the `$list array`. What you can do is to pass the whole array down to JavaScript as JSON encoded and then index into that.

See: [Convert php array to Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618925/convert-php-array-to-javascript)