# How to get value from a PHP array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

Let's say we have one PHP array:

```
$decoded = array(
    'method' => 'getFile',
    'number' => '12345'
);
```

The array data will pass to another JavaScript get function(params).

```
function get(params) {
}
```

How I get the `$decoded['method']` value in JavaScript language in the get function?

Comment: I do not understand, how you can "pass" something from PHP to JavaScript? Is this done by AJAX or simple `<?=…?>`text replacement?

Comment: make sure your php value are converted to javascript value, you only can `$decoded['method']`

Comment: This may help : https://www.codexworld.com/how-to/convert-php-array-to-javascript-array/

Comment: @UweKeim the php array will be passed to the another javaScript file by using curl. So the data will pass as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert php array to Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618925/convert-php-array-to-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$decoded = array(
'method' => 'getFile',
'number' => '12345'
);

?>
<script>
var params =  <?php echo json_encode($decoded); ?>;
get(params);
function get(params){
    console.log(params);
    console.log(params['method']);
}
</script>
```

Use this way. you have to get php variable or array inside javascript by printing or echo. Then you can call function.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript array and PHP arrays are not equal. But the objects of both languages are equal. Then you can JSON encode your array in PHP and pass the encoded value in the javascript.

For example:

**In PHP**

```
<?php 
   $decoded = array(
      'method' => 'getFile',
      'number' => '12345'
   );
?>
```

**In JS**

```
var params = <?php echo json_encode($decoded); ?>;
function get(params) {
   console.log('method', params.method);
   console.log('number', params.number);
}
```