# How to convert array to different type

Tags: php, arrays

i have Array ( [0] => dev2 [1] => dev3 [2] => dev4 )

how to convert to ["dev2","dev3","dev4"]

Comment: Do you mean you want the output to be ["dev2","dev3","dev4"] rather than Array ( [0] => dev2 [1] => dev3 [2] => dev4 ) If yes, refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618925/convert-php-array-to-javascript/12863675

Comment: They both are same. You are getting those indexes because you did print_r();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$old_array = array( 'dev2', 'dev3', 'dev4');
$new_array = json_encode($old_array);
echo $new_array;
```

I hope this is what you want.