# why does Echoing php into JavaScript not work

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to echo a multidimensional array from PHP to js, but it is giving me an error saying that "<" is an unexpected token.

js

```
var products = <?php echo json_encode( $products ) ?>;
```

Php

```
<?php
    // PHP array
    $products = array(
        // product abbreviation, product name, unit price
        array('choc_cake', 'Chocolate Cake', 15),
        array('carrot_cake', 'Carrot Cake', 12),
        array('cheese_cake', 'Cheese Cake', 20),
        array('banana_bread', 'Banana Bread', 14)
    );
?>
```

Comment: Is this the answer to your question? [convert-php-array-to-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618925/convert-php-array-to-javascript)

Comment: Your `.js` file is *probably* not processed on your server as PHP source code. Thus it is sent with that `<?php` stuff to the browser, and the browser does not like that.

Comment: How is the JS code imported into the page? You did not show that. Is it a `<script>` tag that loads a file?

Comment: Duplicate of [How do I pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](/q/23740548/4642212).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

missing `;`:

```
var products = "<?php echo json_encode( $products ); ?>";
```

also:

In order for the `var...` line to be parsed, that line MUST be loaded within `<script>` in a PHP file, not within a separate JS file, which does not get parsed via PHP at all

Comment: The missing semicolon could not possibly cause the reported error, and usually semicolons are not required in JavaScript.

Comment: semicolumn is within PHP, not in JS. And it can cause a PHP error

Comment: The OP says that that line of code is JS code.

Comment: if the OP outputs the expected JS without encapsulating it within "", that would cause the next line to brake JS.

Comment: If that really is a separate JS file loaded from a `<script>` tag however, it almost certainly will be sent raw from the server to the browser, with the `<?php` stuff not touched at all.

Comment: that is true, bit is not clear what he is loading, how, and where... so I am doing a best attempt to answer

Comment: Agreed, @Ron, it is not clear.